# Understanding JPEG compression.

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing

I have some problems in understanding a passage of the JPEG compression algorithm:

Consider an $8\times8$ matrix $M$ that in our case is a "piece'' of a channel (for example the red channel $R$) of the image. The entries of $M$ are integers in the range $[-128, 127]$ that represents the hues of red. At this point we apply the $2D$ DCT (II) transformation (discrete cosine transformation) in order to obtain a ''matrix of frequencies''.

**I don't understand what phisically represent these frequencies!** For example if I have a set of points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and then I calculate the DFT on these points, I obtain the frequencies of the fundamental armonics which constitute the  trigonometric interpolant.

In the case of an image, what is the meaning of the matrix of frequencies coming from the DCT?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think the physical interpretation of the frequencies obtained from the 2D DCT (II) transformation (if there is any) is completely unimportant for JPEG compression. The point of JPEG compression is to "decompose" the "fuction" $M$ into a sum of functions, some of which vary slowly (low frequencies) and others vary quickly (high frequencies). Then you throw away the high frequencies and "hope" that this loss goes unnoticed to the human eye. And there you are - compression.

Comment: For optical imagery, boundaries and edges are typically what make up the high frequency components, while the more continuous and smoother regions make up the low frequencies. [This](http://cns-alumni.bu.edu/~slehar/fourier/fourier.html) page does a pretty good job of explaining it.